# How Data Flow computing differs from Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-data-factory

Knowing that in ADF Dataflows transformations will run in a Databricks cluster in the backgroung, how different (in terms of cost and performance) would be to run the same transformations on a Databricks notebook in the same pipeline?

I guess it will depend on how we set the Databricks cluster but my question is also to understand how this cluster will run in the background. Would it be a dedicated cluster or shared one in the platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each activity in ADF is executed by an Integration Runtime (VM). If you are synchronously monitoring a Databricks job, you will be charged for the Integration Runtime that will be monitoring your job.

Notebook execution in Databricks will be charged as a job cluster. Please create pool and use that pool in ADF. In databricks you will see history of ADF created clusters in pool overview.

During creation of the pool please be careful with settings as you can be charged for idle time. Min idle could be 0 and auto termination time set to low value. If you have dataflow which executes notebooks step by step reuse the same pool can be quicker and cheaper as databricks will not deploy new machine and use existing machine from pool (if it wasn't auto-terminated already).

On the screenshot ADF jobs in pool and min idle settings:
[image]